# Arch Linux - Swapping /boot

Tags: arch-linux, boot

I'm using Arch and last night I was going through the Beginner's Guide and set up all the partitions, downloaded the required base and base-devel files and I thought everything was okay.

However, I realised that since I have Windows already installed, I already have an EFI system partition on `/dev/sdc1` so I didn't need to create a new one at `/dev/sdb1`. I have already generated my `fstab` file so I'm assuming I need to change the boot from `/dev/sdb1` to `/dev/sdc1` - However I'm unsure if this is as simple as editing `/mnt/etc/fstab` or I need to do something a little more complicated.

My second smaller problem is that to get the USB installer to boot, I needed to use the `nomodeset` option, however, I forgot to make it permanent so I need to do it again - but with Arch booting straight into the boot device I can't press `e` on the options menu to add `nomodeset`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try copying the contents of `/dev/sdb1` to `/dev/sdc1` (while preserving the structure of the data) and then change the mount options in `/etc/fstab` to point at `/dev/sdc1` for the `boot` partition. If you are able to boot successfully, that's good but if you aren't, then you can always use a live USB to chroot into your Arch Linux installation and revert the changes. Note that you should use UUIDs instead of partition names in your `/etc/fstab` file.

If you're using `systemd-boot`, edit the `/boot/loader/entries/*.conf` file and add `nomodeset` to the `options` row in the file. Note that I wrote `*.conf` to indicate the file name of the configuration file which can be anything that you've set.
If you're using `GRUB`, I think that you need to edit the `/etc/default/grub` file and add `nomodeset` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and then run `sudo update-grub` afterwards.